# IE9 compatibility list - not working?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

My site is on the IE9 compatibility list so is meant to automatically render as IE8 in this browser.

For the majority of users this works fine for them, but we have been getting a small percentage of IE9 users who can't use parts of the site (javascript seems to be the issue).

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Can this compaitibility list be overrided by the user, or can IE9 version or OS effect this?

Any help appreicated - we are pretty puzzled at the mo!

Comment: Wait while I put on my mind reading glasses so I can guess the URL of your site

Comment: Show us some information. We cannot guess what could be wrong without at least seeing the site... So yes it was a helpful comment. You need to help us help you.